# § compatibility between xelatex/lualatex+{fontspec} and pdflatex+[utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: input-encodings

I'm having trouble with some macros and the § symbol. I can get things working with xelatex/lualatex, but not with pdflatex.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % <- xelatex/lualatex works
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <- pdflatex fails
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\instring#1#2{TT\fi\begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x\ifin@}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\def\A{§ 2|1:3}

Spilt ``\A{}'' at ``|'':
\DeclareListParser{\dopipedlist}{|}
\edef\B{{\A}}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
\begin{itemize}
\expandafter\dopipedlist\B
\end{itemize}

Searching for §:
\if\instring{§}{\A}
Found.
\else
Not found.
\fi

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I want to be able to define `\A` with `§` or `\textsection` or `\S` and have it work regardless of which flavour of *latex is used. (I know § won't work without fontspec/inputenc.)

I've had some success with `\textsection` by using `\noexpand\textsection` and moving to the more robust `InSubStr` from the xstring package, but this is not as neat as I want. `\A` is user provided and it seems unreasonable for an end user to have to decipher TeX's error message and know they need to add `\noexpand`.

Is there any solution that “just works”? It doesn't matter if the back end code is messy. I'm more concerned that `\A` is simple.

Finally, `\A` could potentially contain anything, though the only strange character I want to check for with `instring` is §.

Comment: `\edef\B{{\A}}` is your problem `\edef` should never be used on general text strings, in pdftex § is multiple characters set up to parse and decode utf8 encoding and then multiple font specific code to typeset a § none of that will do the right thing inside `\edef`  (also the `\edef\x`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give the flavor, I define `\itemizelist` so that it splits the given input at `|` (or another character chosen at runtime) and adds `\item` in front of the various pieces. If the piece contains `§`, it is printed red.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,ifxetex}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec} % <- xelatex/lualatex works
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <- pdflatex too
\fi
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\itemizelist}{sO{|}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \purton_itemizelist:no { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \purton_itemizelist:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \purton_itemizelist:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { ##1 } { § }
     {
      \item \textcolor{red}{##1}
     }
     {
      \item ##1
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \purton_itemizelist:nn { no }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\A{§ 2|1:3}

\begin{itemize}
\itemizelist*{\A}
\itemizelist[;]{2:x;§ 3}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The macros are “engine agnostic”, so the result is the same for all of them.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget about xparse! That gave me enough clues to do what I wanted. I see the magic is in generating the variant function with the argument that expands one level (`\cs_generate_variant:Nn \purton_itemizelist:nn { no }`). In my playing around, I couldn't directly define the function in this way. Why is this?

Comment: @DavidPurton It's by design; you can only define functions with arguments `N` or `n` (this can also be `T` or `F`, in relevant cases). Then you can apply the magic of `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`.